# Blender data to numpy array. calling function from another file gives value unpack error

Tags: python, numpy, valueerror

I've got a working simulation and now i'm refactoring my code. I want to put the code that gets and sets data from blender mesh and numpy arrays. vertex positions, edge indices etc.

The following code works fine from its own file put if I put the same function in another file I get the error ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 5, got 3)

```
import bpy
import numpy as np

mesh_object = bpy.context.active_object

def meshToNumpy(mesh_object):
    if mesh_object and mesh_object.type == 'MESH':
        mesh = mesh_object.data
        
        # Extract vertex coordinates as NumPy array
        length = len(mesh.vertices)
        positions = np.empty(length*3, dtype=np.float64)
        mesh.vertices.foreach_get('co', positions)
        positions.shape = (length, 3)
        
        # Extract edges as NumPy array
        edgelength = len(mesh.edges)
        edges = np.empty(edgelength*2, dtype=np.uint8)
        mesh.edges.foreach_get('vertices', edges)
        edges.shape = (edgelength, 2)

    else:
        print("Please select a valid mesh object.")

    #print(mesh, positions, length, edges, edgelength)
    return positions, edges, edgelength, length, mesh

positions, edges, edgelength, length, mesh = meshToNumpy(mesh_object)
print(length)
```

Works fine, but

```
import bpy
import numpy as np
import blendergetset

mesh_object = bpy.context.active_object


positions, edges, edgelength, length, mesh = blendergetset.meshToNumpy(mesh_object)

print(length)
```

This does not.  the first code block is saved as 'blendergetset.py'.

What is happening here? As far as I can tell its exactly the same...

thanks!

I have already tried reducing the number out output variables and if its any more than 3 it doesn't work

Comment: `blendergetset.meshToNumpy` is only returning 3 items, while your other function returns 5.  Why?  That's for you to figure out!  Different 'version'?

Comment: When you write `x,y,z=func(..)`, `func` has to return exactly 3 arguments. Otherwise you get this unpacking error.  So you have to know (not guess) what the function returns.  The `return` of `meahtonumpy` has 5 terms so we know what it returns.

Comment: For debugging purposes, it may be safer to use `args= func(...)`, expecting `args` to be a tuple, which you can then print and check the length safely.

Comment: if I print 'args' it shows all the data, but if i use args[3] i get an error that the index doesn't go that high. There are definitely 5 inputs and outputs so i don't understand. again, it only doesn't work if i import to another file.

Comment: If `len(args)` is 3, then `args[3]` would be wrong.  But without seeing `print(args)` (not that I want to) I can't help.

Comment: Well I changed absolutely nothing and today it works fine!